# Unwanted "doublespace" word in abstract environment

Tags: line-spacing, abstract

I am using an Elsevier template to write a manuscript. I need the abstract to be double spaced. Finally, after trying various options to set the spacing of my abstract it is double spaced. However, my abstract now begins with the word "doublespace". Why is this happening and how to remove it?

[image]

```
%% Copyright 2019 Elsevier Ltd
%% 
%% This file is part of the 'CAS Bundle'.
%% --------------------------------------
%% 
%% It may be distributed under the conditions of the LaTeX Project Public
%% License, either version 1.2 of this license or (at your option) any
%% later version.  The latest version of this license is in
%%    http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%% and version 1.2 or later is part of all distributions of LaTeX
%% version 1999/12/01 or later.
%% 
%% The list of all files belonging to the 'CAS Bundle' is
%% given in the file `manifest.txt'.
%% 
%% Template article for cas-dc documentclass for 
%% double column output.

\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn]{cas-sc} %cas-dc for double columns

\usepackage[authoryear, round]{natbib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace} % line spacing set at introduction

\begin{document}
\let\WriteBookmarks\relax
\def\floatpagepagefraction{1}
\def\textpagefraction{.001}
\shorttitle{XYZ}
\shortauthors{F. Bar et~al}

\title [mode = title]{Title}                      

\begin{abstract}
\begin{doublespace}
\linespread{1.6}\selectfont
 $\leftarrow$ Look at what my abstract starts with... % my problem (see screen clipping)
\end{doublespace}
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
A \sep 
B
\end{keywords}

\maketitle

\doublespacing
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2}
\modulolinenumbers[1]
\linenumbers

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Did this example even compile without errors for you? I get a lot of error compiling this on an up to date TeXLive 2020

Comment: I got three errors, but the commands were ignored. I am writing in Overleaf.

Comment: **never ever ignore compilation errors** even if you get a pdf out. In the mode overleaf is using, it asks latex to make a choice if an error occurs. That might not be a good choice as you see in this example.

Comment: Warnings (orange) can be ignored or dealt with later, but never ignore compilation errors

Comment: Ok thank you. Can you reccomend a way to resolve this, please?

Comment: No idea, that abstract is kind of a beast in that class. Perhaps just ignore double spacing it.

Comment: Just a suggestion: is the `setspace` package loaded?

Comment: Yeah if I could ignore it I would. But it is one of the requirements I have to adhere to...

Comment: @Bernard yes it is

Comment: the environment looks forward to get the optional argument and this breaks here. Add a \relax: \relax\begin{doublespace}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer That worked perfectly, thank you!